# Does an balanced binary tree has an unique form?

Tags: data-structures

Does an balanced binary tree has an unique form?
For example, the node list [1,2,3,4,5]

It seems like following two forms are all qualified with the definition of balanced binary tree. Are they all correct?

```
    2
   / \ 
  1   4
     / \
    3   5
```

```html
    3
   / \
  1   4
   \   \
    2   5
```

Comment: No it doesnt have unique form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There isn't. A balanced tree may have different order based on the order of operations made in order to get to it. Also, there are multiple ways to do a self balancing tree ([Red-Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), [Splay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree)) - all result (usually) in different trees.

A simple counter example with two nodes on AVL tree:

```
insert(1)
insert(2)
```

Will result in no need for rebalancing, and the tree will be:

```
1
 \
  \
   2
```

If you do it the other way around:

```
insert(2)
insert(1)
```

Again, no rebalancing is needed, but the result tree will be:

```
     2
   /
  /
 1
```

Both are valid AVL trees with the same elements, but as you can see - the form is not unique.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of balanced binary search tree OR for that matter binary search tree is much dependent on the sequence of data you provide to it.

Answer (score 2):

With [AVL (self-balancing binary tree)](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/AVLtree.html) you will yield a unique form; provided you have same sequence of data, that in your case is [1,2,3,4,5].

```
   2
   / \ 
  1   4
     / \
    3   5
```